# convert pdf, doc, docx, xls, etc. to rtf in .NET

Tags: .net

I need to allow user to store his documents on a USB flash drive so that they can be opened on any computer.

the idea is to convert common formats (pdf, doc, xls, etc.) to rtf and just show rtf (since that is always available and doesn't require any software to be installed on the pc).

are there any components that can do that?
I don't care if some formatting will be lost, but I need text and images to be preserved.

I'm using .NET, so it would be preferable that component is .NET as well. I guess I could use ActiveX, software would need to run without admin privileges.

another option would be to convert to HTML.
Yet another option would be to use some kind of command-prompt converter.

Answer (score 1):

It is not free, but I believe [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/default.aspx/) can do that.

Comment: I think it can, but rather pricey. I'm trying to find out all options out there before committing to something.